# vi editor behaving weird

Tags: unix, solaris, vi

My `vi` editor has started behaving weirdly since today morning.

When I use keys in command mode, the characters are being overwritten. For example when using 'w' for word jump, it replaces the characters. To make sure something is not wrong with my settings I have removed the `.exrc` file from my home, but its still not working correctly.

I am using solaris 10, shell is ksh and version is: Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0

Example:

`VARCHAR(3)` is changed to `(3) CHAR(3)` on doing word jump.

Any idea how it has changed suddenly? Does it use any other default resource file that might have been changed?

Comment: Have you relaunched your terminal session?  Kill the window and start over is probably both simplest and sufficient.  Failing that, try `stty sane` to reset your terminal to a sane state.  If you have a real green-screen, then you may need to turn it off and on — the usual reboot trick.

Comment: Has your keyboard language settings changed?

Comment: My problem got resolved when I opened a new shell, but I still cant understand what went wrong with the original shell session. I also did a stty sane but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

It need not be a resource file of vi that has been changed. The setting of the environment variable TERM in the original shell session may be wrong. Compare `$TERM` there and in a new shell.